# Can lxml be used to check if xml file is well formed, or is it too powerful?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml

Can lxml be used to check if xml is well formed or is it too powerful? For example it seems to be able to parse even if xml is not well formed. What's the easiest way to check if an xml file is well formed?

Comment: Post the codes and the malformed XML you tried. `lxml` should throw exception in case of not well formed XML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lxml` should've thrown exception when parsing non well-formed XML, for example :

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<multipleroot>
    <noclosingtag>
</multipleroot>
<multipleroot></multipleroot>"""
doc = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

**exception thrown:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\StackOverflow\Python\Q50.py", line 8, in <module>
    doc = etree.fromstring(xml)
  ......
  ......
XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: noclosingtag line 3 and multipleroot, line 4, column 16
```

However if you *explicitly* tell `XMLParser` to recover non well-formed XML, or you're using `HTMLParser` instead, `lxml` may still able to parse the XML :

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<multipleroot>
    <noclosingtag>
</multipleroot>
<multipleroot></multipleroot>"""
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
#parser = etree.HTMLParser()
doc = etree.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

**successfully print parsed XML :**

```
<multipleroot>
    <noclosingtag>
</noclosingtag>
<multipleroot/></multipleroot>
```

Comment: What's the most correct way of catching the exception e.g. if the point of the program is to check if xml file is well formed?

Comment: catch the `XMLSyntaxError`? something like : `try: ... except etree.XMLSyntaxError: ....`

Comment: Riiiiight...I didn't know it was etree.XMLSyntaxError being thrown. I find it unclear in python documentation knowing what kind of exception is being thrown...

Comment: @Celeritas I found it from the error message as posted in this answer : *"XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch:...."*